# C# Databindings to varchar, text fields

Tags: c#, binding, text, ntext

I am using Databindings in my app in this way:

```
textBox1.Databindings.Add(new Binding("Text", myObject, "myObjectField"));
```

Everything is OK, when field in database is type of varchar. Then size of field is defined by me. Problem is when field in database is text or ntext field. Database says that the size of this field (text, ntext) equals 16 and then textBox1.MaxLength is 16 causing fault working.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any scope for changing the database varchar(MAX) and nvarchar(MAX) are essentially wrappers for text and ntext respectively.  They work as other (n)varchars except that they cannot be used in an index but can hold as much as an (n)text field.

Comment: Can you explain the fault in more detail? Error number, Error description ...

Comment: Can you give a better description of the error? Potentially the full error text.

Answer (score 0):

When u take nvarchar as data type with predefined size it will allocate that much memory means fixed lenght instead varchar is variable length ... so my point of view if u know u r taking field which is not take more than u defined character size then use nvarchar or if u need unicode support else use varchar when u have not confidence

Answer (score 0):

There is no errors. For example: I have a table in db with two fields. One of them is "name" (varchar(255)) and the other one is "desc" (text). After binding in C# code, textbox "name" works fine, but binding to the "desc" field not. In effect textbox on form is binded to "desc", i can write only 16 characters of string and then i can't go outside this field. Help please ;)

Edit:
Sorry guys, i resolved this problem. The issue was that I setted max length on value in myObject. After removing, binding is working correctly. Thanks for answers.